# Need dataset online returns

Tags: internet, canada, shopping

Hi i am looking for online sales return dataset for canada or US for my client project. Anything similar to online return maybe ups or fedex returns will also work. Please help onnthis

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: https://github.com/ISU-DMC/dmc2016

theres somewhere a data folder with the raw data as zip.

best, fabi